# ı using flutter in android studio. I have a some project. but have a some files. ı can't see

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, android-layout, installation

I just installed android studio on my computer. I'm watching sample videos, but not all files are visible to me. how can i see some flutter files. Example pubspec.yaml, lib file etc. Can you solve this problem?

Comment: Post some screenshots please.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that you have installed flutter properly following the official documentation of [flutter](https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/windows) also make sure you type : flutter create my_app in the terminal in order to generate all the necessary files for a flutter project and it should look like this : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3on0.png)